# If the ring map $f: A\rightarrow B$ is integral, fibres of $f^*$ are finite, then $f$ is finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If the ring map $f: A\rightarrow B$ is integral, i.e. $B$ is integral over the subring $f(A)$, and each fibre of the induced map $f^*: Spec(B)\rightarrow Spec(A)$ is a finite set, then should $f$ be finite (i.e., $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module)? This is the last part of Atiyah and Macdonald, Exercise 4 of Chapter 8.

I want to use the conclusion of Exercise 15 in Chapter 5 to construct a counterexample, but failed.

Also, by Exercise 12, 13 in Chapter 5, there are general ways to give examples of ring pairs $(B, A)$ such that $B$ is integral over the subring $A=B^G$, for some finite subgroup $G$ of $Aut(B)$, and each fibre of the induced map $Spec(B)\rightarrow Spec(A)$ is finite. So the point now is to give some examples such that $B$ is not finitely generated as an $A$-module. (As Benja's example below, but I cannot show his assertions.)

I make a digression: Does these conditions imply that $f: A\rightarrow B$ is of finite type, i.e., $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra?

Comment: What are your thoughts about this problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Misread the question, and apparently, so did the OP :)

**EDIT:** At the urging of the OP, here is an example: $\text{Spec}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})\to\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$. This is certainly integral with finite fibers, but it's not finite. To see this, merely note that for all $n$ $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{2})\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=n$.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean, do you mean it's not true?

Comment: @Benja Thank you very much, I am only a novice.

Comment: @Alex Wait why is the map finite type? That's not assumed in the problem.

Comment: @Benja Sorry, I've been doing way too much of a book recently where arguments like this are used constantly--I answered without thinking. The answer is trivial as Ben points out :) Integral is exactly the word that fills in the equation _____+ ft= finite.

Comment: @Lao-tzu Forgot to tag you :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis It's ok :) I was confused for one second because proper + quasi-finite implies finite is quite a big theorem! The proof for instance in the stacks project uses things about cohomology and the derived functors $R^if$.

Comment: @Benja How about $\text{Spec}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})\to\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$? :)

Comment: @Alex Youcis Your example seems OK, and even not of finite type!

Comment: @Lao-tzu That's the point :)

Comment: @Alex Youcis Still I don't know how to prove $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ is not finite dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space (even it may be a rather trivial fact). You can write this as an answer (not just in the comment) or give some reference, and I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: @Lao-tzu See edit.

Comment: @Alex Youcis Fantastic! And by (7.9) of the AM book, we immediately see that the inclusion of $\mathbb Q$ in $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ is not of finite type.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood the last part of the exercise. It is asking if $f$ is integral and $f^\ast$ has finite fibers is  $f$ necessarily finite. There is **no assumption** of $f$ being of finite type because a finite type integral morphism is necessarily finite by the Remark before Corollary 5.4, AM.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I should modify the question!